# AngularJS 1.2.26 $animate.enter(...) is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I am writing a directive that will be added to a button. With the directive, the button click will cause the button to be removed from the DOM and be replaced by another button that will actually invoke the action. This provides a verification step.

Currently, I cannot get $animate.enter() to display the second button. The first button dissappears, but the second button does not appear.

The relevant code is below:

**HTML**

```
<label verify class="btn btn-default wide" data-click="resetFilters()">Clear Filters</label>
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module("App").directive "verify", ["$compile", "$animate",
  ($compile, $animate) ->

    directive = {}

    # This directive should be an attribute
    directive.restrict = "A"

    # We do not want to replace any HTML
    directive.replace = false

    # Skip the compilation of other directives
    directive.terminal = true

    # Compile this directive first
    directive.priority = 1001

    directive.link = (scope, element, attrs) ->

      # Save parent element
      parent = element.parent()

      # Remove verify attribute to prevent infinite compile loop
      element.removeAttr "verify"
      element.removeAttr "data-verify"

      # Select the element under the "verify" div, store the "click"
      # function and remove it from the element
      clickAction = if element.attr "click" then element.attr "click" else element.attr "data-click"
      element.removeAttr "click"
      element.removeAttr "data-click"

      # Create a new element from the first one. This will become the
      # verify button
      second = element.clone()

      # Design the verify button
      second.html "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"</span>"
      second.addClass "btn-danger"

      # When the user clicks on the original button, hide it and show
      # the verify button
      element.bind "click", ->
        $animate.leave element, ->
          $animate.enter second, parent, -> console.log "done"

      # When the user clicks the "verify" button evaluate the
      # specified "click" action, hide the verify button, and show the
      # original button
      second.bind "click", ->
        scope.$eval clickAction
        $animate.leave second, ->
          $animate.enter element, parent, -> console.log "done"

      # Compile the element
      $compile(element)(scope)

    return directive

]
```

Comment: Yes. Your answer actually solved it! For some reason I didn't see the notification of an answer..

Comment: The issue was the missing two $apply calls

Comment: Glad you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have, but first you need to reference `angular-animate.js` and add it as a dependent module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Then add your animation class to the element:

```
<label verify class="btn btn-default wide animation" ...
```

Simple CSS example:

```
.animation {
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}
.animation.ng-enter,
.animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.animation.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Since `bind()` is a jqLite/jQuery function you need to wrap the code in a call to `$apply()` to trigger the digest loop manually, and then one additional call in the first callback:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.leave(element, function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        $animate.enter(second, parent, null, function() {
          console.log('Done.');
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that the callback function should be passed as the fourth argument to `$animate.enter`, not the third.

If you are going this route you also need to rebind the click functions manually.

Example:

```
...

second.html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span>");
second.addClass("btn-danger");

var bindElement = function(el) {
  el.bind('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      $animate.leave(element, function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $animate.enter(second, parent, null, function() {
            bindSecond(second);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
};

var bindSecond = function(el) {
  el.bind('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.$eval(clickAction);
      $animate.leave(second, function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $animate.enter(element, parent, null, function() {
            bindElement(element);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
};

bindElement(element);

$compile(element)(scope);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tlDir9qAtd6ePngtvlco?p=preview